# Google Drive API How to get folder id by folder name with auth/drive.file scope

Tags: google-drive-api

I can get the folder id by query with auth/drive scope and upload files.

I need to change the scope of my application from auth/drive to auth/drive.file.

With auth/drive.file.
I could create folder with root alias.
I could upload a file with created folder's ID.
But, I can't get created folder's ID to upload another file.

Scope of auth/drive.file isn't allowd to search any files/folders from root.

Please let me know how to get folder id by name with auth/drive.file scope.

Comment: What is the entire scope list of your app? Upon checking, `drives.list` for querying only utilizes **restricted scopes**; hence, it only works with `auth/drive` and `auth/drive.readonly` scopes. This is because these scopes involve querying for files and folders with broader access.

As per [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/api-specific-auth#drive-scopes), **restricted scopes** *"provide wide access to Google User Data and require you to go through a restricted scope verification process."* Not using these scopes would violate some security requirements.